# Junit ParameterizedTest with expensive setup

Tags: java, unit-testing, integration-testing, junit5, junit-jupiter

Im looking for a way of optimize running multiple parameterized tests with expensive setup

my current code looks like this

```java
    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("test1CasesProvider")
    void test1(String param) {
        // expensive setup code 1
        
        // execution & assertions
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("test2CasesProvider")
    void test2(String param) {
        // expensive setup code 2
        
        // execution & assertions
    }
```

but in that shape expensive setup runs for every testCase, which is not very good
I can split this test into two separate tests and use `@BeforeAll`, then setup runs only once per test, but im looking for a way to keep both cases in one test

Comment: My first question would be "Why do you have such a expensive setup?". It's a smell that something is not wrong in the way you're testing. It feels like the test is an afterthought

Comment: @Bart I don't know if I agree with you! I think it depends on what you are trying to test, especially in integration tests.

Comment: those tests are for search engine,

probably whole test should have one setup method with data for all tests, but we are adding new search fields which require new complex data to verify border cases, so adding it all in one setup might influence other already present tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@Nested` tests in this case, like this way:

```java
public class MyTests {

    @Nested
    @TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
    class Test1Cases {

        @BeforeAll
        void setUpForTest1() {
            System.out.println("Test1Cases: setting up things!");
        }

        @AfterAll
        void tearDownForTest1() {
            System.out.println("Test1Cases: tear down things!");
        }

        @ParameterizedTest
        @MethodSource("source")
        void shouldDoSomeTests(String testCase) {
            System.out.println("Test1Cases: Doing parametrized tests: " + testCase);
        }

        Stream<Arguments> source() {
            return Stream.of(
                Arguments.of("first source param!"),
                Arguments.of("second source param!"),
                Arguments.of("third source param!")
            );
        }
    }

    @Nested
    @TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
    class Test2Cases {

        @BeforeAll
        void setUpForTest2() {
            System.out.println("Test2Cases: setting up things!");
        }

        @AfterAll
        void tearDownForTest2() {
            System.out.println("Test2Cases: tear down things!");
        }

        @ParameterizedTest
        @MethodSource("source")
        void shouldDoSomeTests(String testCase) {
            System.out.println("Test2Cases: Doing parametrized tests: " + testCase);
        }

        Stream<Arguments> source() {
            return Stream.of(
                Arguments.of("first source param!"),
                Arguments.of("second source param!"),
                Arguments.of("third source param!")
            );
        }
    }
}
```

The output in this case was:

```
Test2Cases: setting up things!
Test2Cases: Doing parametrized tests: first source param!
Test2Cases: Doing parametrized tests: second source param!
Test2Cases: Doing parametrized tests: third source param!
Test2Cases: tear down things!
Test1Cases: setting up things!
Test1Cases: Doing parametrized tests: first source param!
Test1Cases: Doing parametrized tests: second source param!
Test1Cases: Doing parametrized tests: third source param!
Test1Cases: tear down things!
```

Comment: But be aware, that afaik surefire does not execute tests in @Nested classes.

Comment: Also, @lukwas Be aware that it is no problem to split the tests in two files...