# Writing test methods with shared expensive set-up

Tags: java, testing, junit, junit5

Imagine this scenario. I need to write a bunch of test methods that all require the same slow and complex set-up. I need to ensure that:

1. Every test method tests only one thing. If I have a myriad of unrelated assertions in one test method, and the test fails, it won't be immediately clear what exactly went wrong (and the test method will be huge, compromising readability and maintainability)
2. Given N is the number of tests that share the set-up, the set-up is not performed N times (because it's slow and tests should be fast). Simply extracting the set-up code or including a `@BeforeEach` method is not an option.
3. Not all test methods are set up the same way. Some may require a fast and simple set-up, others may require a *different* slow and complex set-up. However, all test methods test the behavior of *one* class so splitting it into multiple test classes doesn't feel right

```java
public class SomeTest {
    @Test
    public void testOneThing() {
        // slow and complex set-up
        // assert(s)
    }

    @Test
    public void testAnotherThing() {
        // slow and complex set-up
        // other assert(s)
    }

    // more tests with the shared set-up
}
```

A chat bot suggested this interesting idea:

```java
public class SomeTest {
    @BeforeEach
    public void expensiveSetup() {
        // Perform slow and complex setup here
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("testMethods")
    public void runTest(Runnable testMethod) {
        testMethod.run();
    }

    // Define the test methods as static factory methods returning Runnable
    private static Stream<Runnable> testMethods() {
        return Stream.of(
                SomeTest::testOneThing,
                SomeTest::testAnotherThing
                // Add more test methods here
        );
    }

    // Individual test methods with assertions
    private static void testOneThing() {
        // Perform assertions for one thing
    }

    private static void testAnotherThing() {
        // Perform assertions for another thing
    }
}
```

However, the drawback is that I wouldn't immediately know which assertion runnable failed if something goes wrong, only its index. Replacing lambdas with anonymous classes that override `toString()` would be awkward

What can I do in Junit 5 to meet my criteria?

Comment: What prevents you from using „@BeforeAll“?

Comment: @johanneslink the fact that *some* methods require a different set-up

Comment: @Powet Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of the "complex set up" you have. Describe how the different tests should/will use this complex set up you have. Explain why "extracting the set-up code" isn't an option either or why creating a new test case with just these tests and set up (via `@BeforeAll`) is not an option either.

Comment: @Progman it's irrelevant. The only relevant part is that the set-up is expensive and I'd like to avoid executing it many times for each set of related assertions. I explained why extracting the set-up code isn't an option. Edited to include a mention of `@BeforeAll`

Comment: @Powet Is using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67316175/junit-parameterizedtest-with-expensive-setup an option?

Comment: @Progman I don't see how it solves the problem. What the parameters are going be? If `Runnable`s, I covered it in my original question

Comment: @Powet You can have `@Nested` classes with their own `@BeforeAll` setup, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220889/whats-the-purpose-of-the-junit-5-nested-annotation/51809805#51809805

Comment: @Progman have you considered writing an answer?

Comment: @Powet If https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220889/whats-the-purpose-of-the-junit-5-nested-annotation/51809805#51809805 is solving your problem then this question is a duplicate of that question and should be marked as such. If it doesn't then edit your question to include a detailed description with the restrictions you have why separated test classes or `@Nested` classes won't work for you.

Comment: Note if you don't find anything that does what you want out of the box then you can always write your own extension.

Comment: I don't understand why `@BeforeAll` is not an option, as long as there's at least one test in the class which needs the complex setup. Is the complex setup required once only, or once for each test which needs it? Please edit your question to explain why `@BeforeAll` won't work.

Comment: @tgdavies I explicitly addressed it in the question: *"others [other tests] may require a different slow and complex set-up"*

Comment: Then annotate each of those setups with `@BeforeAll`.